# IBM DB2 Case in Where clause?

Tags: db2

I have a SQL Statement where I have to check on conditions on rows since it has duplicates. 
`Condition1` is to watch if the value from a column in `tb1` is between two values in a two columns of `tb2` but only on rows which has a 'Y' inside.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

tb1.columnA, tb1.columnB, tb2.columnA, tb2.columnB,

CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN CONCAT(tb1.col2,tb2.col2)
    ELSE 'no changes'
END as conditionColumn

FROM
    tb1 left outer join tb2 on tb1.columnX  tb2.columnX

WHERE   

CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN Condition1
    ELSE Condition2
END
```

From what I saw before, a case statement is not allowed in the where clause?
How can I handle this then?

**EDIT**

When I have a 'Y' in tb1.col1
the where clause should output me an ID specified in tb1.columnA and only the rows which values from tb1.ColumnB is between tb2.columnA and tb2.columnB. If it doesn't have a Y inside then it should simply just give me the ID

so I used this, but it gives me an syntax error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

tb1.columnA, tb1.columnB, tb2.columnA, tb2.columnB,

CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN CONCAT(tb1.col2,tb2.col2)
    ELSE 'no changes'
END as conditionColumn

FROM
    tb1 left outer join tb2 on tb1.columnX  tb2.columnX
WHERE   

CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN tb1.columnA = 'MyID'
    AND tb1.columnB BETWEEN tb2.columnA and tb2.columnB
    ELSE tb1.columnA = 'MyID'
END
```

Comment: A `CASE` expression _is_, in fact, allowed inside the `WHERE` clause.  But, what is the logic you want?  What you wrote gives a `CASE` expressions but does not compare it to anything.

Comment: Hello, when in tb1.col1 has a 'Y' inside. I will edit my post

Comment: That doesn't address my comment.

Comment: The logic is to filter the rows and give me only rows, which value from tb1.columnB is between tb2.columnA and tb2.columnB

Comment: Can't you write that with a simple OR? You have either / or col1=Y

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this

```
WHERE   

CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN Condition1
    ELSE Condition2
END
```

then, likely what you are wanting is this

```
WHERE   

    ( tb1.col1 = 'Y'  AND Condition1 )
 OR ( tb1.col1 <> 'Y' AND Condition2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the purpose of a `WHERE` clause...

All a `WHERE` clause does is decide rather or not a given row is returned.  It can't change the data being returned.

To change the data, you need a `CASE` in the columns selected...

something like so...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
         AND tb1.columnB BETWEEN tb2.columnA and tb2.columnB
      then 'MyID'
    ELSE tb1.columnA
END as newColumnA,
    tb1.columnB, tb2.columnA, tb2.columnB,
CASE 
    WHEN tb1.col1 = 'Y'
    THEN CONCAT(tb1.col2,tb2.col2)
    ELSE 'no changes'
END as conditionColumn
FROM
    tb1 left outer join tb2 on tb1.columnX  tb2.columnX
```